# How to access node.js site with direct url without mentioning port 8080 in aws ubuntu, Apache2

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, port

My node.js application is running on port 8080. I want to access it via url without mentioning port number in the URL. How will i achieve this?

for example : 
current : www.domainname.com:8080

Expected :www.domainname.com

Ubuntu os version: 16
Server : Apache2

Need help.

Comment: If you don't specify a port the default one will be used 80 for http and 443 for https. As you mentioned Apache, you can use Apache as a proxy to forward requests to your node application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Nginx as a reverse proxy for your node js application and mentioned your port in nginx config file.(you can create new config file or you can use default one /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)

Install pm2 and Use pm2 tool to keep running your nodejs application in the background.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install pm2@latest -g

pm2 start myapp.config.js (replace myapp.config.js with YOURAPP.js )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your immediate response. I am using pm2 already but do not want to use nginx. wanted to do it in apache. how can i do it in apache?